# How to stop Firefox from collapsing the title, tabs, search and bookmarks bars

Tags: browser

I'm in Firefox 106.0.2 on Xubuntu 20.04, and suddenly find Firefox is collapsing most of the top of my window whenever my pointer goes down into the body.  I find this frustrating -- I have a large enough monitor that I have plenty of space, and I'm having trouble getting the gestures just right to see my tabs and such again.,

I don't see anything in settings about this and can't find the Customize selection mentioned in an answer to a recent related question.  Can I shut it down somehow?

Comment: You probably hit the `F11`-key accidentally and swiched to fullscreen-mode, hit `F11` again to swich off fullscreen-mode.

Comment: @mook765 You are 100% correct.  Make it an answer, and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as if you accidentally hit the <kbd>F11</kbd> key and switched to full-screen mode.

Hit the <kbd>F11</kbd> key again to switch off full-screen mode.